# Error: (1431.1) FASTA-Reader: Warning: FASTA-Reader: Title is very long: 1127 characters (max is 1000)

Tags: warnings, fasta, blast, genetics

I'm running blastx on my *de novo* transcriptome assembly. While the program is still running I've been obtaining errors like this one:

```
Error: (1431.1) FASTA-Reader: Warning: FASTA-Reader: Title is very  long: 1127 characters (max is 1000)
```

...and others, where the number of characters varies. I've searched for this specific error online but I don't seem to find anything regarding it. I was hoping that someone that has run across it can help me understand what it means and specially, if I should stop the run and start with different parameters or make some change to my assembly.

Answer (score 1):

I'm facing the same problem in the ncbi-blast-2.2.29+ version.
Then, I used an older version (2.2.25+) and makeblastdb worked fine to me, without these two message errors:

Error: (1431.1) FASTA-Reader: Warning: FASTA-Reader: Title is very long: 1141 characters (max is 1000)

Error: (1431.1) FASTA-Reader: Warning: FASTA-Reader: Ignoring FASTA modifier(s) found because the input was not expected to have any.

Well, you can use an older version too, until the developers fix the problem.

Comment: I've worked out what the strange modifiers warning is about, and reported that to the NCBI as a bug - see http://blastedbio.blogspot.co.uk/2014/04/error-1431-fasta-reader-ignoring-modifiers.html

Answer (score 0):

Did you ever figure this out? I'm running into the same issue with fasta files generated by a Trinity assembly. The fasta file is not altered in any way, so I'm not sure why there would be a problem. I did some research and found the source code that generates this error:

```
void CFastaReader::ParseTitle(
00848     const SLineTextAndLoc & lineInfo, IMessageListener * pMessageListener)
00849 {
00850     const static size_t kWarnTitleLength = 1000;
00851     if( lineInfo.m_sLineText.length() > kWarnTitleLength ) {
00852         FASTA_WARNING(lineInfo.m_iLineNum,
00853             "FASTA-Reader: Title is very long: " << lineInfo.m_sLineText.length()
00854             << " characters (max is " << kWarnTitleLength << ")",
00855             ILineError::eProblem_TooLong, "defline");
00856     }
```

This code was found at: [enter link description here](http://www.ncbi.nlm.nih.gov/IEB/ToolBox/CPP_DOC/doxyhtml/fasta_8cpp_source.html)

Comment: I've also emailed the user group, I'll keep you posted.

Comment: What I did was basically crop the title of the FASTA sequences and only have the necessary codes. For example, in the reference database, use only the code for the gene and transcript and delete all the rest. You can extract the headers and make the correspondence later if needed. The same for the assembly headers, if you want to make reciprocal blast. After I did this, everything worked.

Comment: I ended up doing the same thing, and you're right, it worked just fine after that. Thanks so much!

Answer (score 0):

I ended up using a one-liner to parse the extraneous information out of the fasta headers:

```
sed -e 's/>* .*$//' original.fasta > truncated.fasta
```

But I'd recommend doing that on a test file first, as your headers are most likely going to be different than mine.

Thanks for the pointer!